Listen to watch os notification click
I'm using Flutter to develop an App for ios that has a Watchos companion app, for notification, I'm using FCM, when the iPhone is closed I receive the notification on the watch, and when I click the notification it opens the watch app. The issue is that I can't read the data of the notification to display the right UI.
Any one knows how to solve this?
class AppDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    
    func handleUserActivity(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        print("[notification] \(userInfo?.keys)")
        
    }
    
    func didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError(_ error: any Error) {
        print("[notification] Failed to register remote notification : \(error)")
        
    }
    
    func didRegisterForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Record the device token.
        print("[notification] registered with token:  " +  deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) })
    }
    
    
    func didReceiveRemoteNotification(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (WKBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("[notification] notification received!!! ")
        handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
               completionHandler(.newData)
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("[notification] notification received..." )
           let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("[notification] notification received \(userInfo) " )
           handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
           completionHandler([.sound, .banner])
       }

       // This method will be called when the user taps on the notification and the app is opened
       func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
           print("[notification] notification oppened... " )
           let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
           print("[notification] notification oppened \(userInfo) " )
           handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
           completionHandler()
       }

       func handleNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
           if let customData = userInfo["customData"] as? [String: Any] {
               let messageId = customData["messageId"] as? String
               let sender = customData["sender"] as? String
               let content = customData["content"] as? String
               // Handle the data as needed
               print("Message ID: \(messageId ?? "N/A")")
               print("Sender: \(sender ?? "N/A")")
               print("Content: \(content ?? "N/A")")
           }
       }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
                
        print("[notification] Application did Launch!!" )
        Task {
            do {
                let success = try await UNUserNotificationCenter
                    .current()
                    .requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
                
                guard success else { return }
                
                // 4
                await MainActor.run {
                    WKExtension.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
  }


For anyone who is having the same issue, for me, I was able to fix the issue by updating the applicationDidFinishLaunching function with this:
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
                
        
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        
        center.delegate = self
        
        print("[notification] Application did Launch!!" )
        Task {
            do {
                let success = try await UNUserNotificationCenter
                    .current()
                    .requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
                
                guard success else { return }
                
                // 4
                await MainActor.run {
                    WKExtension.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications(   )
    
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

